# how to host multiple symfony projects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony1, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm trying to host multiple symfony projects on one machine. I would like to have localy the same folder stucture as on my hosting remote server (can only use .htaccess here, can't access httpd.conf). It should be like:

```
  -(public_html or htdocs)
    -symfony_project1
    -symfony_project2
    -symfony_project3
```

and the addresses:

local:

```
localhost/symfony_projectX
```

should be redirected to

```
localhost/symfony_projectX/web/(index.php)
```

---

(Pay attention that localhost/symfony_projectX/config can't be accessible at all! Tutorials deal with that by setting documentroot to web/ , but i dont know what to do with pultiple projects)

---

and on server:

```
myaccount.myhostingserver.com/symfony_projectX
```

should be redirected to

```
myaccount.myhostingserver.com/symfony_projectX/web/(index.php)
```

later i would like to have projects on server accessible by different domain name, for example:

```
mycoolestproject.com
```

should be the address for

```
symfony_project2
```

and the question is: how to get this done, only by using .htaccess on server side and .htaccess and http.conf localy? (if it is possible at all)

Comment: Have you looked at VPS hostings? These days they are so available and cheap I don't really see why you would be bothering with such loopholes which are so easily exploitable and a bad idea anyway. There are even plenty of shared hostings that allow setting up virtual hosts as well if you are on a really tight budget.

Answer (score 0):

**For your first issue** you have two options:

1. You can use a simple PHP script to redirect HTTP Headers to its appropiate path (file) like this:

   ```
   <?php 
     header('Location: http://myaccount.myhostingserver.com/symfony_projectX/web/'); 
   ?>
   ```
2. You can use HTML refresh meta tag, like this:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <title>Symfony ProjectX</title>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://myaccount.myhostingserver.com/symfony_projectX/web/index.php">    
   </head>
   <body></body>
   </html>
   ```

**For your second issue** you add the following to your root folder .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myaccount.myhostingserver.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ symfony_projectX/web [L]
```

And append lines to repeat this behavior for each domain you need to be redirected:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mycoolestproject.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ symfony_project2 [L]
```